# Is /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid strong keying material?

Tags: random, uuid

I've been looking at ways to generate a strong 256 bit/32 byte symmetric key for the HMAC_SHA256 algorithm.  I stumbled upon the /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid file.

According to [man random(4)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html): "The read-only files **uuid** and boot_id contain random strings like 6fd5a44b-35f4-4ad4-a9b9-6b9be13e1fe9.  The former is generated afresh for each read, the latter was generated once."

The string from `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` looks ideal for this purpose. I can remove the '-' chars and end up with a 32 bytes of randomness.

Is this a valid approach to generate a cryptographically strong source of keying material?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Perl Data::UUID a strong symmetric key source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873332/is-perl-datauuid-a-strong-symmetric-key-source)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  Here I'm proposing a different tack of using /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid as a source of randomness.  According to the documentation for random(4) the contents of the uuid file is a random number derived from /dev/random which is an interface to a hardware based entropy pool for Linux.

Comment: A version 4 (variant 1) random UUID contains 122 random bits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)

Answer (score 13):

An old question but in case anyone stumbles on it, I wouldn't advise this.

`/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` is a type 4 (random) UUID with certain semantics - it's not just a string of random hex characters. For example you'll see the first digit in the third group is always a 4.

For 256 random bits just read 32 bytes from `/dev/random` (uses external entropy, can block) or `/dev/urandom` (never blocks).

Comment: wow, I just did `cat /dev/random` and... yeah don't `cat` it

Comment: @user yeah.. you'd want to do something like ```dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/stdout bs=32 count=1``` or ```head /dev/random |cut -b 1-32``` and if your console window gets messed up from any of the random bytes that are printed hit ```ctrl + c``` a few times then run the command ```reset```

Answer (score 0):

o172.net is the best answer, would comment on it directly but cannot.

`/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` is based on `urandom` but it is best to grab from urandom directly.

This below is how to get it from the shell, the following gets 32 ascii hex bytes:

```
echo $(tr -dc a-f0-9 < /dev/urandom | dd bs=32 count=1 2> /dev/null)
```

You can change the char set via the `tr` params, the bytes by the

```
dd bs=
or not use tr
```

and get random binary.

Answer (score -4):

Would you rely on a well-defined deterministic pseudo-random algorithm for key generation? That's the question basically.

I'd say, take the UUID as a base for your key, but do one pass of encryption on it using a secret key of yours.

Comment: what would be the point of doing one pass of encryption on a string that is already guaranteed to be perfectly random?

Comment: It's not perfectly random, in fact it's perfectly NON random. There's a deterministic algorithm that generates it.

Comment: If you already have a good secret key, why use a UUID as a "base" for it? Use the key itself, or encrypt any arbitrary bitstring with the key to generate a new key - the result will be just as random as if you encrypted a UUIS.

Comment: Because the longer a key remains in use the higher the risk of compromise, so you have to rotate keys periodically, and to generate your "arbitrary string" you are well justified in using a guid.