# Is Perl Data::UUID a strong symmetric key source?

Tags: perl, key, sha1, uuid, hmac

I'm considering using Data::UUID Perl module to generate a 256 bit symmetric key for use with the HMAC_SHA256 algorithm. Each call should give me a unique string of 128 bits so I'm thinking of doing something like the following:

`use Data::UUID;`

`my $ug    = new Data::UUID;`

`my $uuid1 = $ug->to_hexstring($ug->create());`

`my $uuid2 = $ug->to_hexstring($ug->create());`

`my $256_bit_key = $uuid1 . $uuid2;`

Is this key cryptographically strong?

Answer (score 6):

No.

Use [Crypt::OpenSSL::Random](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aOpenSSL%3a%3aRandom) or another crypto-strong random number generator.

To be more precise, you can get some bytes from the CRNG, convert them into an ASCII string, and then use that to do the hash against.

Comment: @cjm Thanks.  Could you say a little about why concatenating the two UUIDs is not strong?  Trying to learn here.

Comment: @pfarber: random number doesn't imply crypto strong. Use a crypto-random number for crypto.

Comment: @cjm I'm confused.  I thought the point of strong crypto was to use a key that is as close as possible to being random, i.e. that you can't do any better than random.

Comment: The intention of UUIDs is uniqueness, not randomness. These are not the same thing. In fact, adding an element of non-randomness (e.g. the MAC address of the machine that generated the identifier) actually *improves* uniqueness.